# select orders from first time customers

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need help building a SQL query that returns orders from customers who have only ordered once.

The tables and relevant fields are as follows:

```
Order        Customer       
-------      -----------     
orderId      customerId    
orderDate     
customerId     
etc.
```

I'm looking for a result set of Order records where there is only one occurence of the customer id. For the following data set...

```
[orderId]    [customerId]     [orderDate]    [etc.]
----------   ------------   ------------   ------------
o1           c1                 1/1/14        foo
o2           c2                 1/1/14        baz
o3           c3                 1/3/14        bar
o4           c2                 1/3/14        wibble
```

I would like the results to be

```
[orderId]    [orderDate]    [etc.]
---------    -----------    ------
o1           1/1/14         foo 
o3           1/3/14         bar
```

Orders o2 and o4 are ommitted because c2 has ordered twice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry, didn't put my failed attempt. This is what I tried...

```
SELECT customerId,
       orderId,
       orderDate,
       Count(*)
FROM   Orders
GROUP  BY orderId,
          orderDate,
          customerID
HAVING Count(*) = 1
ORDER  BY orderId
```

It appears to return all the orders.

Comment: Your failed attempt probably returns all the orders because `orderDate` and `orderID` are in the GROUP BY clause.  If you want a `Count` of orders by `customerID`, you can only GROUP BY the `customerID`.

Comment: That makes sense Robert, but I get this error message if I remove orderID: Column 'Orders.OrderID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Right; they can't be in the SELECT either.  If you're looking to do this in a *single* query, see Lamak's suggestion below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following (assuming SQL Server 2005+):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            N = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY customerId)
    FROM Orders
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE N = 1
```

Since sometimes a pedestrian approach is preferred over complex CTEs, you can use a derived table if you want (but since it's using the `OVER` clause, you'll still need SQL Server 2005+):

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT  *,
                N = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY customerId)
        FROM Orders) T
WHERE N = 1
```

Alternatively (if for example you are in an older than 2005 version of SQL-Server), you can use the `GROUP BY / HAVING COUNT(*)=1` method to find customers with only 1 order and then join back to the `Orders` table (no need for aggregate functions in all the columns):

```
SELECT o.*
FROM Orders o
  JOIN
    ( SELECT customerId
      FROM Orders
      GROUP BY customerId
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    ) c
    ON c.customerId = o.customerId ;
```

or use `NOT EXISTS` (no `COUNT()` needed and it works even in MySQL):

```
SELECT o.*
FROM Orders o
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT 1
      FROM Orders c
      WHERE c.customerId = o.customerId 
        AND c.orderId <> o.orderId
    ) ;
```

Comment: The last two examples are the best for my situation because the aggregate functions prevented me from performing a Stuff function on another table.

Answer (score 2):

This will list all first-time customers in your `ORDERS` table.

```
SELECT [customerID],
       MIN([orderId])   AS [orderId],
       MIN([orderDate]) AS [orderDate],
       MIN([etc.])      AS [etc.]
FROM   [Orders]
GROUP  BY [customerID]
HAVING Count(*) = 1
ORDER  BY [customerID]
```

In order to bring back all the additional columns you would need to wrap them in an aggregate such as `MIN/MAX`.

It is arbitrary which to use as there will only be one row per group anyway. This does assume that all columns in the table are of datatypes valid for such aggregation however (examples of datatypes that aren't are `BIT`, or `XML`)

Comment: This doesn't return the desired result set

Comment: I'm confused. I understand answers are supposed to be helpful, but this answer isn't complete; even if they're intended to "nudge" the OP towards the right direction.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a complete answer.  It never did.  Stack Overflow never required that.

Comment: I added my failed attempt to show what I tried. I wish I could "figure out the rest", but I don't seem to have the SQL skills to pull it off.

Comment: The aggregate functions are the key. Learned a lot today.

Comment: @ClayDavis yessir!  Otherwise, it will try to pull all records.  `MIN` and `MAX` are your friends for only pulling one record.

Comment: @ClayDavis just take notice that if you aggregate every column (without the `HAVING` of course), they won't all come from the same row (except by sheer coincidence). A much more predictable and deterministic method would be using the ranking functions, like in [Lamak's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21559850/61305).

Comment: @AaronBertrand The `HAVING Count(*) = 1` takes care of that in this case, right?

Comment: @ypercube in this specific case, yes, but for any other implementation where you want one row per customer (which is almost every other scenario I've seen on SO), this approach doesn't translate well at all.

Comment: Yes, I agree, if someone expects for example, to change that to `HAVING COUNT(*)=2` and get the customers with 2 orders, it will be a mess.

Comment: +1 This satisfies the requirements perfectly. @Lamak's solution is superior, IMHO (because it is much more flexible), but this one is correct nevertheless.